# Thread Safety: Multiple threads reading from a single const source

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

What should I be concerned about as far as thread safety and undefined behavior goes in a situation where multiple threads are reading from a single source that is constant?

I am working on a signal processing model that allows for parallel execution of independent processes, these processes may share an input buffer, but the process that fills the input buffer will always be complete before the next stage of possibly parallel processes will execute.

Do I need to worry about thread safety issues in this situation? and what could i do about it?

I would like to note that a lock free solution would be best if possible

Comment: For C++11 `const` means thread safe and the standard library works this way. For user defined types they should work the same way but that requires them to be implemented properly. I'll try to find the standard reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the process that fills the input buffer will always be complete before the next stage of possibly parallel processes will execute

If this is guaranteed then there is not a problem having multiple reads from different threads for const objects.

I don't have the official standard so the following is from [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> **17.6.5.9 Data race avoidance**
>
> <sup>3</sup> A C++ standard library function shall not directly or indirectly modify objects (1.10) accessible by threads
>   other than the current thread unless the objects are accessed directly or indirectly via the function’s non-const
>   arguments, including this.
>
> <sup>4</sup> [ Note: This means, for example, that implementations can’t use a static object for internal purposes without
>   synchronization because it could cause a data race even in programs that do not explicitly share objects
>   between threads. —end note ]

---

Here is the [Herb Sutter video](https://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) where I first learned about the meaning of `const` in the C++11 standard. (see around 7:00 to 10:30)

Answer (score 1):

No, you are OK. Multiple reads from the same constant source are OK and do not pose any risks in all threading models I know of (namely, Posix and Windows).

However,

> but the process that fills the input buffer will always be complete

What are the guarantees here? How do you really know this is the case? Do you have a synchronization?

Comment: The chain of processes is being broken down into multiple stages.The stages will be executed in such a way that the system appears to be single threaded. Parallel processing will only be allowed to happen within the stages, and the system will wait until each stage is complete before another stage that is dependent upon the current one is executed.

Comment: @AlexZywicki, devil is in the details. System will wait - on **what**?

Comment: That is indeed the question, I suppose at the moment that is the desired behavior that i intend to make happen. I was debating using a std::future/promise or using std::atomic_bool with a condition variable. I'm still playing around with design ideas